# spring-boot @Scheduled pool-size debugging

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-scheduled

I am developing an app using the spring-boot @Scheduled annotation and I am trying to make it use multiple threads by setting the pool-size. Now I wonder how I actually can see that there are multiple threads running?

Does IntelliJ support debugging of pooled runners?

Answer (score 1):

Any active threads in your JVM should be shown in IntelliJ Debug tab in *Threads* view if you click on threads that you can event[customize](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-views.html#customize-threads-view).

[image: Active Threads]